# visual studio 2017 adds new line before semicolon after while

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

My visual studio 2017 auto formats following c# code:

```
while (source[--start] != '\"');
```

into:

```
while (source[--start] != '\"')
    ;
```

I haven't found any related settings which would be related to this rule.

Why does it add new line and tab before semicolon in this case?
Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to specify which language, as each one implements formatting settings differently.

Comment: Edited. THanks for hint.

Comment: Can you verify it in a clean VS 2017 with initial extensions?

Comment: I don't see anything in the built-in formatting options which would do this.  There are rules for newlines around braces, but not for single statements in a control block.  Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: I just tested it on different computer and it adds only space before ; which is acceptable. I have no clue why does it add a new line before ; on my primary computer.